# How to return a variable using a discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I've followed a tutorial and created a simple discord bot that I'm messing around with, the bot will connect to a server and when a user types in `!ping` the bot will return a message. I would like to change it to print a defined variable set globally. I'm not sure how to do this

I'm new to Javascript and making discord bots so I'm not sure how to print a variable in the way I would like, Below is the code.

```
var money;
money = 0;

bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {

            // !ping
            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: "Hello World",
                });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
         }
     }
});
```

So at the top, i've defined the integer and its name as well as the value 0
now instead of the bot saying "Hello World" when I type `!ping` I would like it to return the value that money is equal to, but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `sendMessage` is deprecated, use `textchannel#send` instead.

To include a variable in your string you can use any of the following examples:

```
channel.send('A variable: ' + var);

channel.send(`A variable: ${var}`);
```

where `var` is the variable you would like to include in your string.

So in case of your money example, you would do:

```
message.channel.send(money);
```

Comment: Adding on, you may want to give these a read: [`"foo" + variable + "bar"`: appending multiple values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Long_literal_strings) and 
[`\`foo ${variable} bar\``: template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Also, here is the documentation for the [`.send()` method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) you should be using.